Can "opening ceremony" be used to denote a university's new student convocation?
I've seen such a ceremony being called "opening ceremony" in many Chinese universities. Is it acceptable?
An "opening ceremony" is defined as "a ceremony at which a building or other facility is declared to be open or an event begins" (Oxford Dictionaries Premium).
For such a university ceremony, I've also seen "new student convocation," "matriculation ceremony," and "opening ceremony." Which one is preferred?

The opening part of opening ceremony can mean speeches for a new building that opens. But it's a very common term for the starting point, initiating talks, first series of announcements, or welcoming event to a school year or even political party convention.

If it's an English-speaking university, it presumably has a name for the event. If you're talking about a Chinese university then "opening ceremony" is probably OK (although you should consider if the term could refer to other events and be ambiguous). Are such things common in American or other English-speaking university? British universities don't seem to have such ceremonies, although there will be various events to welcome students, organised either by student unions or departments/faculties.

'Opening ceremony' may refer to the rituals performed at the dedication of a new complex, building etc (as with the King opening a new hospital / hospital wing, say), a one-off. But it may also refer to the iterative ritual performed at the opening of a regular event etc, such as the London Fashion Show or the Paris Olympics (when there may also be a valedictory closing ceremony).

Usually, a welcome day is organized for new students already having completed the registration formalities.

Every school has their own names for this ceremony, assuming they even have one.
